# Is it really necessary to explicitly define "undefine" even when the define is commented out?

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation, undef

I was having some problems with this code executing:

```
#if TRACE
            dbgLog = new LogInfo( "PlatypusCE" );
#endif
```

This was occurring even though "TRACE" was commented out above, right after a large block of general comments:

```
//#define TRACE
```

Once I added this below it:

```
#undef TRACE
```

...so that it is:

```
//#define TRACE
#undef TRACE
```

...it works as desired, though (the "#if TRACE" code doesn't execute).

Is it really necessary to undefine something that has not been defined (is commented out)? It seems bizarro.

Comment: Any chance that `TRACE` was being defined through [compiler switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) and not `#define`? Did you look at the project settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, in the profiles Debug and Release, Visual Studio will define the `TRACE` constant. You can change this behavior in the project settings (in the `Build` tab). The `DEBUG` constant is similar, active by default in the Debug profile (but not Release).

Answer (score 2):

`TRACE` is one of the two constants defined by default for debug builds:

[image: TRACE]